# Как проверить версию node.js перед инсталляцией пакетов?

Tags: node.js, npm, install

Доброго дня, можно ли сделать так чтобы команда npm install проверяла установленную версию node и останавливалсь если нет требуемой версии. на проекте один из проектов требует ноду версии 7 и ниже и если выше - то просто выдает кучу загадочных ошибок по которым причину установить сложно
в документации нашел что можно сделать так вот "engines" : { "node" : "<8.0" },
но к сожалению такой вариант ничем не помогает и все так же валится куча загадочных ошибок

Answer (score 1):

Для этого можно использовать preinstall скрипт в package.json:

```
{
   "...",
   "scripts": {
     "preinstall": "node check-version.js"
   }
 }
```

Ну и в самом скрипте check-version уже проверить, что версия соответствует нужной. Для этого достаточно проверить `process.version` и выбросить читаемое исключение, если версия не подходит. Например `throw new Error('Use node with version < 8')`